# Spring Boot JPA with REST Service

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-rest

I know that such questions were asked ([Did not find handler method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38817471/did-not-find-handler-method) ), but after trying multiple solutions I'm still stucked.
So my problem is: I can't use both REST and JPA in my project.
com.db.ruf: WRepository.class:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
@Component
public interface WRepository <T, ID extends Serializable>
        extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {
}
```

com.db.ruf: WRepositoryImpl.class:

```
public class WRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable>
        extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements WRepository<T, ID> {

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    // There are two constructors to choose from, either can be used.
    public WRepositoryImpl(Class<T> domainClass, EntityManager entityManager) {
        super(domainClass, entityManager);

        // This is the recommended method for accessing inherited class dependencies.
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }
}
```

com.db: MyRepositoryFactoryBean.class

```
public class MyRepositoryFactoryBean <R extends JpaRepository<T, I>, T, I extends Serializable>
        extends JpaRepositoryFactoryBean<R, T, I> {
    /**
     * Creates a new {@link JpaRepositoryFactoryBean} for the given repository interface.
     *
     * @param repositoryInterface must not be {@literal null}.
     */
    public MyRepositoryFactoryBean(Class<? extends R> repositoryInterface) {
        super(repositoryInterface);
    }

    protected RepositoryFactorySupport createRepositoryFactory(EntityManager entityManager) {

        return new MyRepositoryFactory(entityManager);
    }

    private static class MyRepositoryFactory<T, I extends Serializable> extends JpaRepositoryFactory {

        private EntityManager entityManager;

        public MyRepositoryFactory(EntityManager entityManager) {
            super(entityManager);

            this.entityManager = entityManager;
        }

        protected Object getTargetRepository(RepositoryMetadata metadata) {

            return new WRepositoryImpl<T, I>((Class<T>) metadata.getDomainType(), entityManager);
        }

        protected Class<?> getRepositoryBaseClass(RepositoryMetadata metadata) {

            // The RepositoryMetadata can be safely ignored, it is used by the JpaRepositoryFactory
            //to check for QueryDslJpaRepository's which is out of scope.
            return WRepository.class;
        }
    }
}
```

com.rest.: WebadminRESTController.class

```
@RestController
@Component

public class WebadminRESTController {

    @Autowired
   WRepository<ExternalLink, Long> wRepositoryImpl;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/allExternalLinks", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<?> allExternalLinks() {
...
     }
}
```

com:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.db.ruf", repositoryFactoryBeanClass = MyRepositoryFactoryBean.class)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com", resourcePattern = "com.*")

@EntityScan({"com.db"})


public class WebadminApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebadminApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

In this case I get:

> Did not find handler method for [/allExternalLinks]

If I change 
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com", resourcePattern = "com.*") to @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com") or @ComponentScan I get:

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   'com.db.ruf.WRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies
>   as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

I really don't know what's wrong.
Could anyone be so kind to explain it?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Vera, please explain, what exactly do you want to do? It is enough only 3 classes to work with data-jpa and data-jpa-rest... Did you read this [manual](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/)?

Comment: The deal is that I have problem with a cache of entityManager. Whan I called "save" using simple "interface  RepoName extends  CrudRepository<ExternalLink, Long>", I got incorrect data because the saving entity is additionally changed by db trigger. I need to call refresh or something like that.So according https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.0.M1/reference/html/repositories.html I tried to implement methods above.

Comment: Я создал [чат](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148969), можем пообщаться там...

Comment: Мне очень жаль, но не выйдет:  You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here.

Comment: How about here: https://gitter.im/stack-over-flow/SpringDataJPA-REST ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `@Repository` on `WRepositoryImpl.java`. And edit `WebadminRESTController.java`:

`@Autowired
 WRepositoryImpl<ExternalLink, Long> wRepositoryImpl;`

Comment: When I do that I get:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.Class<?>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

Comment: Try `@Service` on your WRepositoryImpl class, and delete `@Component` from your interface. In your WebadminRESTController class, edit the specified line to     `@Autowired
   WRepositoryImpl<ExternalLink, Long> wRepositoryImpl;`

Comment: Sorry, try `@Repository`

Comment: > org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionExcept‌​ion: No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.Class<?>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
.....(

Answer (score 0):

Accidentally I found solution (don't think that it is the best one, but at least it works):

```
public interface  ExternalLinksRepo extends  CrudRepository<ExternalLink, Long> {
...
}
```

and:

```
public class WebadminRESTController {

   @Autowired
   ExternalLinksRepo wRepositoryImpl;
...}
```

Then wRepositoryImpl is automatically created as instance of WRepositoryImpl

Thanks to all, especially to Cepr0